# Errors after updating to PHP 7.2

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm updating my church website PHP from 5.2 to 7.2 and I am receiving errors both on the site and within Wordpress. Here are the on-site errors:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant style - assumed 'style' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /nfs/c05/h03/mnt/75123/domains/villanovabaptist.com/html/wp-content/themes/zion/functions/admin-setup.php on line 19

and

> Warning: Use of undefined constant churchthemes - assumed 'churchthemes' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /nfs/c05/h03/mnt/75123/domains/villanovabaptist.com/html/wp-content/themes/zion/functions/admin-setup.php on line 87

I don't know much about PHP so I haven't tried anything.

Here is the code referenced in the error above.

```
<?php

// Options panel stylesheet

function churchthemes_admin_head() { 

    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/functions/admin-style.css" media="screen" />';

}



// Load different stylesheet

function churchthemes_wp_head() { 

    //Styles

     $style = $_REQUEST[style];

     if ($style != '') {

          echo '<link href="'. get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/styles/'. $style . '.css" rel="stylesheet" />'."\n"; 

     } else { 

          $stylesheet = get_option('church_alt_stylesheet');

          if($stylesheet != ''){

               echo '<link href="'. get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/styles/'. $stylesheet .'" rel="stylesheet" />'."\n";         

          }

     } 



      // Custom.css insert

      echo '<link href="'. get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'."\n";   



     // Favicon

    if(get_option('church_custom_favicon') != ''){

        echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="'.  get_option('church_custom_favicon')  .'"/>'."\n";

     }    



     // Custom CSS block in Backend

    $custom_css = get_option('church_custom_css');

    if($custom_css != '')

        {

            $output = '<style type="text/css">'."\n";

            $output .= $custom_css . "\n";

            $output .= '</style>'."\n";

            echo $output;

        }



    //Decode

     $decode = $_REQUEST['decode'];

     if ($decode == 'true') 

        church_option_output(); 



    // Localization

    load_theme_textdomain(churchthemes);    



}



// Add Encrypted setting field to footer for debug purposes

function church_option_output(){



    $data = get_option('church_settings_encode');

    echo '<meta name="generator" content="' . $data . '" />';



}





// Use legacy comments on versions before WP 2.7

add_filter('comments_template', 'legacy_comments');

function legacy_comments($file) {

    if(!function_exists('wp_list_comments')) : // WP 2.7-only check

        $file = TEMPLATEPATH . '/comments-legacy.php';

    endif;

    return $file;

}







?>
```

Comment: Those are just warnings. They're telling you that you have the symbols `style` and `churchthemes` that are not  surrounded with quotes, so PHP thinks they're supposed to be constants. But since PHP isn't finding any constants defined with those names, it's treating them as strings instead. If they're supposed to be strings, then add quotes around them, e.g. change `style` to `'style'`. If they're supposed to be constants, then find out where they were supposed to be defined and ensure that they're being defined correctly.

Comment: Would you recommend anyone I could hire to fix my php/wordpress code? I'm awful with php.

Comment: Why not contact the theme author to ask them about a fix? https://www.vandelaydesign.com/zion-church/ Hopefully they would be willing to help you out for free

Comment: Thanks. I have contacted them. Hopefully they aren't too busy.

Comment: The “fix” would be to replace `$_REQUEST[style]` with `$_REQUEST['style']`, and `load_theme_textdomain(churchthemes);` with `load_theme_textdomain('churchthemes');` … you can apply both changes manually, if you want to. If the theme author fixed this via an update that would be the preferable option though, because if they don’t, but publish other updates and you fetch a new theme version from them, you’d be dealing with the same issue again.